# What is the actual entropy of the Universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, universe, estimation

I know that it depends on scale, but for example, for an experimenting coissing a coin, What was the maximum run, 20 , 30, that doesn´t influiate taking account that the velociy of the information is

$  SBH=\frac{c^3A}{4G\hbar}=\frac{c^3\pi(1000)^2100}{4G\hbar} $

Letting the experiment of coining a coin 100 times (it takes less than 100 s) SBH it would be a probability in 12E-24 irrelevant. It would be very useful in practise  for example, when we do bayesian analysis. I am not working on concrete exemples, but I will think another one. See you soon

Comment: You'll have to define what you mean by *the entropy of the universe*. The universe is not in equilibrium and possibly not a closed system so it is far from clear if it makes any sense to calculate an entropy for it.

Comment: Universe is closed by definition. I ask for entropy en general, to every scale, it is of course a different, but I wanna mean this when I talk about human experiment scale